# Prompting a user to fill in meta data when they upload a file to SP Online Library

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, metadata

Morning.

I've got a library with some mandatory fields but when the user uploads a file they are not getting prompted to fill in any of the meta data. Anyway to get the form to pop up by default, I've got a horrible feeling from looking around that there isn't...

Answer (score 0):

This is a "feature" of the SharePoint Modern UI that required metadata is not enforced.  Instead, All Modern View libraries have a built-in view that the user can choose titled "Files That Need Attention".
[image]